# Store static locations and info iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, database

Lets say that I have gps coordinates for 1000 stores and a short text to each one. What would be the best way to store this information? SQL? One more thing to consider is how to load the information into the app. It don't seem to be a smart thing to load everything direct, the best way seems to be loading the stores in the specific area but how do I search for those stores? Is that easy to do in SQL? As you see I don't have so much experience of database programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storing in SQLite3 file would be best for the moment as you have lots of data and through a db, you can fetch the required data (via query) back on demand.

as for the getting stores of specific area - assuming you want to locate nearby stores within 10 KM of radius.
This will not be hard to fetch from db.
I am no server expert but can give you a guideline which will work:-
you will be having current lat/long, you will have lat/long in the table as well for each row.
may be a server guy could help you create you a query with formula where you can fit the distance calculation formula in 'where' clause's condition and you will get the records of nearby (10 KMs) places records.